# Neural network activation/output

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, neural-network

Here is my code (for a neuron in a MLP network):

```
double summation = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < weights.length; i++) {
    summation += inputs[i] * weights[i];
}

double normalized = Math.tanh(summation);
if (normalized > 0.9 || normalized < -0.9) {
    activated = 1;
} else {
    activated = 0;
}
```

I think it is incorrect. Is the output supposed to be the normalized value, or is it always limited to 0 or 1?

Comment: Different models use different activation functions.

Comment: This is just a standard MLP. Nothing fancy.

Comment: FYI, The answer / output you refer to is activated and its set to either 0 or 1 in your code. What model do you indent to implement anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* simply use the sign of the output, but normally, the output of a neuron is required to be continuous and differentiable, so a real-value between -1 and 1 (since you've chosen the tanh function) would be more appropriate, especially if you are going to train the model using backpropagation.

Comment: So would I say: activated = Math.tanh(summation); ?

Comment: That's one way of getting a continuous, differentiable output between -1 and 1.

Comment: Yes, but would that be correct? I don't think assigning 0 or 1 to the output would be very effective.

Comment: I will try what you have said. Thanks!

Comment: Well, I don't get why you were initially assigning 0 or 1 to the output? Did you have a reason? If so, my answer might not be correct.

Comment: I think it was just a misunderstanding.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6535/discussion-between-conner-ruhl-and-sancho)

Answer (score 3):

A common activation function is Sigmoid. It's nice because it can squash the neuron values between two bounds. So sum up all the values, then apply your activation function

Here is an excerpt of my Sigmoid Function from my code:

```
/**
 * シグモイド関数: Sigmoid function
 */
private double sigmoid(double x) {
    return (1.0 / (1 + Math.exp(-x)));
}
```

Also check out my Github examples of Neural Networks (Code in Java, C++ versions also available)
https://github.com/kennycason/neuralnetwork/
https://github.com/kennycason/ml

Answer (score 0):

There is no "correct" activation function for a neuron.  What you want is some function which is clamped between two values, and monotonically increasing.  A hyperbolic tangent function (your "normalized" function) will do this very nicely, without outputs running from -1 to 1, as the inputs run from -inf to +inf.

There are a bunch of common activation functions, though.  A signum function (output negative one if the input is less than zero, otherwise output one) is also valid.  Another is the logistic curve that Kenny Cason mentions, but note that you can actually replace the -x in Kenny's function is -kx, where k is some constant.  In that way, you can generate a family of sigmoid curves with a tighter or looser transition region around zero.

None is really more "correct" than the other.  (Unless you are doing backpropagation, in which case the signum function is non-differentiable, and won't work for you.)

However, that said, I don't understand what your "if" statement is doing.  It looks like you're creating a function which transitions from one, down to zero, and back up to one as the inputs move from -inf to +inf.  That's not what you want at all.  (If you were going from negative one to zero to positive one, that would be okay.)